# TableView reloads data after Modal Segue in Swift & Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, segue

I am trying to build a messaging feature into a new app I have been developing. This is working just fine, but when I switch from the Messaging View Controller (the one where one sends and receives messages) to the Messages View Controller (the one where users with which to message are displayed) using a Modal segue, the TableView reloads. This results in a brief moment where the TableView is blank after the segue. At first, I thought this might be due to my function that is called in ViewDidLoad that calls for the TableView to reload, but after removing it, the TableView still reloaded. I am not quite sure as to what I can try from here. I apologize in advance for the nesting. I am going to clean it up later, but it works for now. Any help? Code below:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    getEmployers()
}

func getEmployers() {

    print("ONE")
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

    Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid!).child("Upcoming Jobs").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            print("TWO")
            let array = Array(dictionary.keys)
            var numInArray = 0
            for item in array {
                Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid!).child("Upcoming Jobs").child(item).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                    if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                        print("THREE")
                        let euid = dictionary["Employer"] as? String
                        numInArray += 1
                        if !self.employerUIDs.contains(euid!) {
                            self.employerUIDs.append(euid!)
                            Database.database().reference().child("users").child(euid!).child("Messages").child(uid!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                                if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                                    let array = Array(dictionary.keys)
                                    var array2 = [Int]()
                                    for item in array {
                                        var item2 = item
                                        item2 = item2.replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "", options: .literal, range: nil)
                                        item2 = item2.replacingOccurrences(of: ":", with: "", options: .literal, range: nil)
                                        item2 = item2.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "", options: .literal, range: nil)
                                        print(item2)
                                        array2.append(Int(item2)!)
                                    }
                                    array2.sort(by: >)
                                    print("SUBSTRING:")
                                    var timeStamp = String(array2[0])
                                    timeStamp = self.insertChar(char: "-", location: 4, string: timeStamp)
                                    timeStamp = self.insertChar(char: "-", location: 7, string: timeStamp)
                                    timeStamp = self.insertChar(char: " ", location: 10, string: timeStamp)
                                    timeStamp = self.insertChar(char: ":", location: 13, string: timeStamp)
                                    timeStamp = self.insertChar(char: ":", location: 16, string: timeStamp)
                                Database.database().reference().child("users").child(euid!).child("Messages").child(uid!).child(timeStamp).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                                        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                                            let recentMessage = dictionary["Message"] as? String
                                            self.createUser(uid: euid!, countOfArray: array.count, num: numInArray, message: recentMessage!, time: array2[0])
                                        }
                                    })
                                }
                                else {
                                    //print("WE ARE NOT YET MESSAGING" )
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    })
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return numEmployers
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell2") as? EmployerTableViewCell
    tableView.rowHeight = 80
    if indexPath.row < employers.count {
        cell!.setInfo(fn: employers[indexPath.row].firstName, ln: employers[indexPath.row].lastName, lastMssg: employers[indexPath.row].lastMessage, lastDate: employers[indexPath.row].dateOfLastMessage)
    }
    return cell!
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "MessagesToMessaging" {
        let val = tableView?.indexPathForSelectedRow
        uidOfOtherUser = employers[val![1]].uidOfEmployer
        tableView.deselectRow(at: tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any code in viewWillAppear/willDisappear/didAppear etc...?

Comment: @SlavenkoMiljic I do not

Comment: Is that Firebase code? My wild guess would be that you reload the table somewhere in you code every time your Firestore data changes and you change the data somehow during the segue.